# String to map for flutter dart

Tags: string, flutter, dart, dictionary

```
{"ABB": {"23-Feb-2023": {"Script": 0, "instrumentType": "Stock Futures", "change": -15.8, "pChange": -0.5, "bidPrice": 3162.9, "bidqty": 500, "askPrice": 3168.1, "askqty": 250, "expiryDate": "23-Feb-2023", "LTT": "2023-02-21T15:30:03.411537"}}}
```

How can I convert this `String` to `Map` for .dart file?

I have tried model class but get error.

Comment: This is a Map already. What do you try to do?

Comment: Have you tried ```jsonEncode()``` function

Answer (score 2):

In Dart use `jsonDecode` to get a `Map`:

```dart
String json = '{"ABB": {"23-Feb-2023": {"Script": 0, "instrumentType": "Stock Futures", "change": -15.8, "pChange": -0.5, "bidPrice": 3162.9, "bidqty": 500, "askPrice": 3168.1, "askqty": 250, "expiryDate": "23-Feb-2023", "LTT": "2023-02-21T15:30:03.411537"}}}';
Map<String, dynamic> map = jsonDecode(json); 
print(map['ABB']['23-Feb-2023']['instrumentType']); // Stock Futures
```